# Python list indexing with bool values

Tags: python

I am not able to comprehend the below python code by how it is giving the output

```
["A", "B"][False] # A
["A", "B"][True] # B
```

Comment: value of `True` is 1 and values of `False` is 0

Comment: `int(True)` and `int(False)` this will also give 1 and 0 respectively

Comment: And `{1, True}` gives 1, `{True, 1}` gives `True`.

Comment: Thanks everyone. But why `0 is False` giving `False` since bool is a subclass of int?